# Uncaught TypeError: contract.addNewOrg is not a function ; Cannot connect to metamask and fetch data

Tags: blockchain, web3js, metamask, contract

The issue that I found is from `contract.addNewOrg($("#txtAddThirdAddress").val(),$("#txtAddThirdName").val(),6,(req,res)=>{`

```
//Add Third Party Verification Org
$('#btnAddThird').click( function() {
$("#lblResultAddOrg").html("") ;
contract.addNewOrg($("#txtAddThirdAddress").val(),$("#txtAddThirdName").val(),6, 
(req,res)=>{
    $("#lblResultAddOrg").html(" Registered!!");
    localStorage["LoggedInUserType"] = 2; //TPVA
    window.location.href="index.html";
   })
});
```

Your reply is highly appreciated. I'm still learning with the code.

Below is the loadContract:

```
var contract = "";

if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
 web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
  } else {
 // Set the provider you want from Web3.providers
  web3 = new Web3(new 
   Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
 }

  window.ethereum.enable()
   .then(function (accounts) {
    console.log(accounts[0]);

    web3.eth.defaultAccount = accounts[0];

    var contractabi = new web3.eth.Contract([ABI], 'address');

    console.log(contract);
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using syntax from the [ethers.js](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/) library, but based on the question tag and the error message it seems that you're using a different library - [web3js](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.1/).

Web3js uses the `methods` property of `Contract` class, and then you need to explicitly state that you want to [send()](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.1/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-send) a transaction.

```
contract.methods.addNewOrg(params).send(
    {}, // options object, see the linked docs
    (err,res) => {} // callback function
);
```

Comment: Hi, sorry because im new to this. but what do i put after ".send( "?

Comment: @SitiHafizah You can either pass the callback function as shown in my answer and your question, or resolve the `Promise` using `await`. Example: `const response = await contract.methods.addNewOrg(params).send(options);`

Comment: Is it like this? contract.methods.addNewOrg(params).send($("#txtAddThirdAddress").val(),$("#txtAddThirdName").val(),6,(err,res)=>{}

Comment: @SitiHafizah The `params` are supposed to be the values from jQuery. So `contract.methods.addNewOrg($("#txtAddThirdAddress").val(),$("#txtAddThirdName").val(),6).send({}, (err, res) => {console.log(res);})`;

Comment: 0h~okay
So i don't need to include this code? 
$("#lblResultAddOrg").html(" Registered!!");
        localStorage["LoggedInUserType"] = 2; 
        window.location.href="index.html";

Comment: @SitiHafizah You can include that inside the callback function, after you've validated that the transaction went through.

Comment: i put it like this,i don't if it is correct or not 


`$('#btnAddThird').click( function() {
    $("#lblResultAddOrg").html("") ;
    contract.methods.addNewOrg($("#txtAddThirdAddress").val(),$("#txtAddThirdName").val(),6).send({}, (err, res) => 
        {$("#lblResultAddOrg").html(" Registered!!");
        localStorage["LoggedInUserType"] = 2; //TPVA
        window.location.href="index.html";}); 
    
});`

Comment: after that, i received this errors:  `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addNewOrg')`
    `at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous>` 
    `at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch` 
    `at HTMLButtonElement.v.handle`

Comment: @SitiHafizah Then your `contract` variable is not correctly initialized.  See the docs for examples of initialization: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.1/web3-eth-contract.html

Comment: before this, the errors were mostly from the contract so I edited until there are no errors but I think it still some issues on the contract code. I already put the `contract code` above. maybe there are errors that I didn't know about.